# Trying to dynamically grow a static array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have to dynamically grow a static array in this struct I've made (I COULD use vectors but it specially asks me to use a static array and copy the elements so please don't ask me to use vectors).

Problem is I get segmentation faults and I don't know why. When I create a new instance of my object it sets an array with a length (currently 5 to test). I then run this code when resizing the array but it isn't working.

```
if (used == (length-1)) {
            length *= 2;
            T* newArr = new T[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < used; i++) {
            newArr[i] = items[i];
            cout << "Copied" << endl;
        }
        items = newArr;
    }
```

So it seems to copy to addresses over to the new array OK and seems to only copy the appropriate number of items. Used determines how many items have been added whereas length holds the size of the entire array. Such that when I create a new array the length should be double how many are used. When I try and assign items to newArr I get a segmentation fault so I'm wondering if that code is correct or if it's crashing there. I;ve tried debugging it line by line but can't tell if it's breaking there or not.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Seeing the declaration of items would be helpful.

Comment: I'll add it in a sec I'm not sure that's my problem I think my check of where the last item of the array breaks after I create the new array somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Q: "I COULD use vectors but it specially asks me to use a static array and copy the elements so please don't ask me to use vectors..."

A: Then the question is fundamentally flawed ;)  You SHOULD use vectors ;)

If you really want to amuse your instructor, I'd encourage you to use`malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` instead of "new" and "delete" ;)

Meanwhile - you're probably getting a segmentation fault by overwriting "newArr[]".  "newArr[]" might be too small if "used" is a lot bigger than length.

Just a guess - using a debugger would clearly show you exactly what's happening.

Q: What compiler and debugger are you using?

Comment: It turns out it was a pointer error. While I was reassigning the array properly I had another pointer called "position" which returned my current position in the array that wasn't being set to an instance of my new array. All working.

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
delete[] items;
```

before the reassignment